# Best Way to Solder/Desolder Surface Mount Components

Tags: pcb, soldering, surface-mount, rework

I recently got my hands on some old motherboards/PCB's, and even though I know reusing parts from old PCB's is not as good as using new parts, I was wondering what the best way is to solder/Desolder small surface mount components such as this: [image]

Comment: Blob of solder covering whole row of pins and hot tweezer (which is expensive but very useful). Somewhat less suitable is covering with solder blob and then heating with hot air.

Comment: @venny Hot tweezers?

Comment: For example the JBC PA120. Tweezer or tweezers, both spelling seem to be correct.

Comment: If the bottom of the board is completely flat, you can use a hot plate.  Either use a purpose-built unit or put a thick (1") piece of aluminum on an electric griddle or fry pan.  This works - I just removed some parts from a dead board using this method today.  Note this is not a a great method if there are through-hole parts that stop the PCB substrate from sitting right on top of the hot surface.  Even a small air gap reduces the heat transfer significantly.

Comment: If you're absolutely set on desoldering SMD components (which isn't really recommended, generally), I would use a heat gun and some tweezers. I would expect that is the most reliable way to heat up the pins evenly.

Comment: Some heat guns are not very good at controlling temperature -- overheating can damage the components, and also make nasty fumes as the PCB gets scorched. It's especially a problem for the kind of board in the photo, multi-layer with large copper areas under many chips -- all that copper sucks heat away from the solder joints.

Comment: turn the board upside down over a bowl and heat the back with a blow-torch whilst tapping it to dislodge the lossened parts.  do this is a well ventilated area and wear at-least eye protection.  the PCB will be destroyed but most parts will be salvaged as only parts sontacting the PCB get heated, and only hot enough to melt the solder. this works well for through-hole parts too.

Comment: @MarkU I think it goes without saying that if you're going to use a hot air tool to desolder, you should use one that works properly.

Comment: "Rough" heat guns are, like a blow torch, best applied from the other side of the board - you even stand a chance to desolder some of the connectors, which usually get destroyed far before semiconductor parts if blasted with hot air directly. About the fumes: as soon as you see any delamination, STOP heating that spot - the air cushion under the peeled-off layer will cause it to heat FAR quicker, and indeed get scorched in seconds.

Comment: "reusing parts from old PCB's is not as good as using new parts" ... for hobbyist use, one could argue even better (free and you get to build a library of rather exotic stuff)... getting parts off them  is what old PCBs are really there for :)

Comment: People seem to use everything from blow torches, to hot air guns to hair-dryers, to sledgehammers... Now we just want to decide if this site is Electrical Engineering or DIY (there's another site for that). As in, if we should encourage some manner of professionalism or if anything goes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redneck SMD removal:
As you can see from the comments above, it depends what kind of equipment you have and what you are willing to buy. If you are trying to rescue random components from old circuit boards, I'm guessing you might not interested in spending hundreds on new equipment. I can give you a few tips when it comes to removing things with a simple soldering iron, solder, and some tweezers.

Two terminal devices are not too difficult, especially if they are small. The trick is to keep both sides hot at the same time so you can lift it off the board. Adding more solder to each pad provides some extra "thermal mass" so that the blobs of solder stay molten for longer after you move the iron away. Apply very slight upward pressure on the component with your tweezers while moving the soldering iron back and forth to the solder blobs on each side. Sometimes you have to move back and forth fairly quickly, pausing briefly at each side long enough to make a thermal connection. If you are having trouble with this add a bit more solder. This method also works for small chips, such as ones with a set of 4 pins on two sides.

Chips are more difficult, especially largish ones. If they are too big they are pretty much impossible with this method. As stated above, put a blob of solder over each set of pins. This adds thermal mass and makes it so you can heat up one set of pins all at the same time. Unfortunately, for larger chips you probably can't provide enough heat to such a large mass of solder to keep it molten using the "back and forth" method above. I also find it difficult to use tweezers in this case. Instead, I slip a thin, sharp object under a corner of the chip (such as an Xacto knife or very small flat head screwdriver) and apply slight upward leverage while slowly alternating between heating up each set of pins. The chip will slowly migrate upward off the board. The most important moment to be apply leverage is obviously as a set of pins goes from molten to non-molten; that is when it becomes cemented in its new position. Sometimes each little move upward is imperceptible, it can take a bit of effort.

The last step is to get the excess solder off the parts using something like soder-wick.

Obviously this process is very difficult and has a good change of damaging things! For better results, see more expensive equipment options noted above. If you don't care about the circuit board and nothing is working, you can always pry the component off with force -- if the pads rip off the board before the chip breaks, success! Then you can just unsolder the copper pads from the pins. This works well for sturdy components like potentiometers and large surface mount inductors and capacitors.

Comment: Ps all of this is much easier if you secure the board in a vice first. If you don't have one, try setting something heavy on the edge of the board.

Answer (score 4):

For some unknown reason, I felt compelled to perfect my skill at this very thing. I suppose it was a sense it would come in handy for rework or for recovering interesting components from electronic scrap boards.

The main thing I found is that pre-heating the board is critical. I suppose there are various improvised ways to do this, perhaps a blow dryer duct-taped to blow across the bottom of the board; but I use a Hakko FR-830:

[image]

Once the board is nice and toasty (say 100-120°C, maybe 3-5 minutes pre-heating), I use a hot air rework tool like this to heat the component I want from the top with maybe 270°C hot air:

[image]

Most components will come off very cleanly with a second or two of hot air applied from the top. Applying a paste flux helps keep too much solder from clinging to the leads of the removed component.

When I started, I just used the hot air from the top and that took a long time (20-30 seconds) and seemed to stress the components with heat. The capacitors in particular would start to smell. With the pre-heating, it's so quick it seems most components barely feel a thing :)

I know it's a bit of an investment, but if you're serious about it, I think a few hundred bucks for hot air will make you a lot better at it.

I found these videos helpful when I was exploring the process:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZDdbDa32_I
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3MX0T5lLDw

Answer (score 1):

I use a $2 butane torch and a small screw driver. aim the torch, fire, and use the screw driver to push any parts that I need. It told only few seconds. of course, you can use $2000 pro de-soldering station, but why bother. these parts cost cents to a dollar.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to fry random bond wires inside the part, so that you don't immediately notice that it is broken, but get to trouble-shoot it further down the line... very inexpensive, right?